# Click on SVG image selenium python

Tags: python, html, selenium, svg

I am trying to use selenium for clicking on a svg element in order to close a pop up:

```
<div class=" light-ui-pop-up--header">
<svg name="ClosePopUp" class="pop-up--close-btn" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 14 14" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M14 1.41L12.59 0L7 5.59L1.41 0L0 1.41L5.59 7L0 12.59L1.41 14L7 8.41L12.59 14L14 12.59L8.41 7L14 1.41Z" fill="#ffffff"></path></svg>>
```

Following previous answers on stack overflow, I have tried:

```
wd.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="light-ui-pop-up--header"]/*[name()="svg"][@id="Root"]').click()
```

and

```
wd.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="light-ui-pop-up--header"]/*[name()="svg"][@name="ClosePopUp"]').click()
```

But in both cases, I have got the same error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class="light-ui-pop-up--header"]/*[name()="svg"][@id="Root"]"}
```

How could I close the emergent pop up with selenium python on this page:
https://data.anbima.com.br/debentures/JTEE11/caracteristicas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below locator:

```
wd.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@class=' light-ui-pop-up--header']/*[local-name()='svg']").click()
```